# How to Bypass Cloudflare with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using python selenium over a cloudflare protected site. Seems to be stuck on the 5 second part.  I tried using the undetected-chromedriver. it doesn't work as well. Any other way to bypass it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
def test():
    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl') 
    time.sleep(100)

test()
```

Comment: You're not going to have a good time trying to bypass a system that is literally designed to block what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have seen massive botting (account generation) on sites with cloudflare before. I wonder how they bypass the cloudflare system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {     'source': ''' delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array; delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Promise; delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Symbol; ''' })` , to bypass cloudflare automized browsers checking.

Also add:

`options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled") options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.5615.165 Safari/537.36") options.add_argument("accept=*/*")`

This one: `options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")` tells cloudflare that we are not bot, other options are needed to scrap elements from cloudflare based websites.